# Where is the error?

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution, conditional-expectation

I am trying to compute expectation of $X\mathbb I_{[X+Y\le a]}$ where $a$ is a fixed positive integer, $X$ is discrete uniform random variable taking values from $1$ to $a$, and $Y$ another random variable of unknown distribution, independent of $X$. I need it as part of a proof I am doing. My calculations are as follows:
\begin{align}
E(X\mathbb I_{[X+Y\le a]})&=E(E(X\mathbb I_{[X+Y\le a]}|X+Y\le a))&&(\text{By tower property})\\
&=E(E(X|X+Y\le a))\\
&=E(E(X|X\le a-Y))\\
&=E\left(\dfrac{a-Y+1}{2}\right)&&(\because X|X\le b\sim \mathrm{dunif}(1,2,\dots,b))\\
&=\dfrac{a+1}{2}-\dfrac12E(Y)
\end{align}
Now my problem is that, the random variable of which I want to calculate expectation is non-negative, but the expectation that I am getting is negative if $E(Y)>a+1$, which is possible. So what is the problem in my calculations?? Also, how do I sort that problem out?

Comment: Is $Y$ positive ? Negative ? What is the support ?

Comment: Support of $Y$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$, only that is known.

Comment: After a few mistakes of my own I've added the correct answer: you mistakenly forget that $a-Y$ can be negative.

Answer (score 2):

Focus on the computation of $\mathbf{E}\left[X\mid X \leq a - Y\right]$ You have 2 possibilities:

- If $Y=y > a$ then $\mathbf{E}\left[X\mid X\leq a - y\right] = 0$ as $X$ has zero mass outside its support.
- If $Y = y < a$ then
  $$\mathbf{E}\left[X\mid X\leq a - y\right] = \sum_{x=1}^ax\,p(x\mid a,y) =  \frac{1}{a-y}\sum_{x=1}^{a-y}x = \dfrac{a - y +1}{2}$$
  because the conditional probability simplifies to
  $$ p(x\mid a,y) = \dfrac{\mathbf{P}(X=x, X\leq a-y)}{\mathbf{P}(X \leq a - y)} = \frac{a}{a(a-y)}\mathbb{I}_{x \leq a - y} = \frac{1}{a-y}\mathbb{I}_{x \leq a - y}$$
  Therefore the expectation over $Y$ becomes
  $$\sum_{y=1}^{a-1}p_Y(y)\frac{a-y+1}{2} = \frac{a+1}{2}\mathbf{P}(Y<a) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{y=1}^{a-1}y\,p_Y(y)$$
  This is positive because the second term is bounded as
  $$\sum_{y=1}^{a-1}y\,p_Y(y) \leq (a-1)\mathbf{P}(Y<a)$$
  which yields that your quantity is bigger than $\mathbf{P}(Y<a)\dfrac{1 - a + 1 + a}{2} > 0 $